# Plot on a pdf file using matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf, plot

I have a 2D plot from a paper and I want to compare my results with it. I am using Matlab and I wonder is there a way I can plot my data on top of the pdf file I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: huh.... No I dont think so. Matlab can plot in MATLAB figures only. Also, why would you do that? This looks like an XY problem

Comment: You might be able to overlay the plot generated in matlab with the original graph - but you might be better off obtaining the data plotted in the pdf and comparing the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make a snapshot of the plot in the pdf and save it as an image file. Then you could extract the data from the plot, for example with this tool from fileexchange:
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit

you can then plot your data and the data from the plot in a new figure.

Another option to keep the original figure design is plot the image, scale the axes and overlay your data on the image. I hope it helps